# Flash Time Stretching

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, signal-processing

I am looking to implement time-stretching in an AS3 Flash application. I have integrated SoundTouch, however, the quality is not fantastic. We do not require the algorithm to be real-time. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are processing Speech, I updated SoundTouch-AS3 as follows:-

Sequence: 40
SeekWindow: 15
Settings-Overlap: 8

The quality is much better.

Comment: Another option would be to use Sonoport -- fantastic library, however, it is $49.00/year subscription /// http://www.sonoport.com/